# Drop down value disappear closing when I click drop down to inspect, find xpath. How to find drop down value which collapse as soon as I click on it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

How to get drop down value or xpath in selenium when drop down is not of Select type.
How to find drop down value xpath of div type elements?
I am clicking on drop down value to find xpath and it is collapsing and hiding?
I am not able to find drop down values in dom html file.
#React #Dropdown values Xpath.
Dynamic Drop down Xpath Selenium
How to avoid drop down closing after i clicked the drop down, actually i want to read the drop down values

I am clicking on drop down value to find xpath and it is collapsing and hiding?
I am not able to find drop down values in dom html file.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Delete everything from Dom->Event Listeners-> focusout.**
If focusout is not present , find **blur** and delete everything from there.

Answer (score 0):

I see, so when you try to interact with the inspector, the dropdown closes. There’s a trick you can use to handle this. In your HTML, right click on the  tag, then select Break on > subtree modifications:

Like the below *example*:

[image]

What this will do is pause your debugger anytime the page changes, so that you can inspect elements in real time as they change.